# How many times do I break my own rule?

Tags: code-golf, string, number, grid, word-search

### Introduction:

In my recent [*<s>Strikethrough</s> the Word Search List* challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/243844/s%cc%b6t%cc%b6r%cc%b6i%cc%b6k%cc%b6e%cc%b6t%cc%b6h%cc%b6r%cc%b6o%cc%b6u%cc%b6g%cc%b6h%cc%b6-the-word-search-list) I mentioned the following:

> When I do the word-search puzzles, I ***(almost)*** always go over the words in order, and strike them through one by one.

In some cases I do them in reversed order as a change of pace, although that doesn't matter too much right now. When I do them in the correct alphabetical order however, I sometimes already see the word after the one I'm currently searching for. In those cases, I usually 'sneakily' strike through that next word already, before I continue searching for the actual current word.

In almost™ all cases, this occurs when both words have the same starting letter, and the next word that I find accidentally is in a horizontal left-to-right direction.

##### Brief explanation of what a word search is:

In a [word search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_search) you'll be given a grid of letters and a list of words. The idea is to cross off the words from the list in the grid. The words can be in eight different directions: horizontally from left-to-right or right-to-left; vertically from top-to-bottom or bottom-to-top; diagonally from the topleft-to-bottomright or bottomright-to-topleft; or anti-diagonally from the topright-to-bottomleft or bottomleft-to-topright.

### Challenge:

Today's challenge is simple. Given a grid of letters and a list of words, output the maximum amount of times what I describe above can occur.

We do this with two steps:

1. Find all words from the given list which can be found in the grid in a horizontal left-to-right direction.
2. For each of those words, check if the word before it in the given list starts with the same letter.

**Example:**

```
Grid:
JLIBPNZQOAJD
KBFAMZSBEARO
OAKTMICECTQG
YLLSHOEDAOGU
SLHCOWZBTYAH
MHANDSAOISLA
TOPIFYPYAGJT
EZTBELTEATAZ

Words:
BALL
BAT
BEAR
BELT
BOY
CAT
COW
DOG
GAL
HAND
HAT
MICE
SHOE
TOP
TOYS
ZAP
```

Horizontal left-to-right words:

[image]

Word-pairs of these horizontal left-to-right words, with its preceding word in the list:

```
Words:
BAT,BEAR   ← B
BEAR,BELT  ← B
CAT,COW    ← C
GAL,HAND
HAT,MICE
MICE,SHOE
SHOE,TOP
```

From these pairs, three start with the same letters, so the output is `3`.

### Challenge rules:

- As you may have noted above, we only look at the word directly preceding it. For the `BELT` in the example, `BALL`,`BAT`,`BEAR` are all three before it and start with a `B` as well, but we only look at the word directly preceding it (`BEAR` in this case), and the counter would only increase by 1 for the output.
- If the very first word in the list is a horizontal left-to-right word, there is obviously no word before it.
- The list of words is guaranteed to contain at least two words, and all words are guaranteed to be present in the given grid.
- You can take the inputs in any reasonable format. Could be from STDIN input-lines; as a list of lines; a matrix of characters; etc.
- You can optionally take the dimensions of the grid as additional input.
- All words are guaranteed to have at least two letters.
- You can assume each word is only once in the grid.
- You can assume the list of words are always in alphabetical order.

### General rules:

- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in bytes wins.
  Don't let code-golf languages discourage you from posting answers with non-codegolfing languages. Try to come up with an as short as possible answer for 'any' programming language.
- [Standard rules apply](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet/2422#2422) for your answer with [default I/O rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/), so you are allowed to use STDIN/STDOUT, functions/method with the proper parameters and return-type, full programs. Your call.
- [Default Loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.
- If possible, please add a link with a test for your code (e.g. [TIO](https://tio.run/#)).
- Also, adding an explanation for your answer is highly recommended.

### Test cases:

```
Inputs:
JLIBPNZQOAJD
KBFAMZSBEARO
OAKTMICECTQG
YLLSHOEDAOGU
SLHCOWZBTYAH
MHANDSAOISLA
TOPIFYPYAGJT
EZTBELTEATAZ

BALL
BAT
BEAR
BELT
BOY
CAT
COW
DOG
GAL
HAND
HAT
MICE
SHOE
TOP
TOYS
ZAP

Output: 3
```

---

```
Inputs:
ABC
SRO
KAX

AB
ASK
ARB
ARX
AX

Output: 1
```

---

```
Inputs:
WVERTICALL
ROOAFFLSAB
ACRILIATOA
NDODKONWDC
DRKESOODDK
OEEPZEGLIW
MSIIHOAERA
ALRKRRIRER
KODIDEDRCD
HELWSLEUTH

BACKWARD
DIAGONAL
FIND
HORIZONTAL
RANDOM
SEEK
SLEUTH
VERTICAL
WIKIPEDIA
WORDSEARCH

Output: 1
```

---

```
AYCD
EFGH
DCBA

ABC
AYC
CB
CBA
CD
EF
EFGH

Output: 4
```

Comment: Just to be 100% sure, the list of words is always in alphabetical order?

Comment: @Neil Woops.. In the linked challenge it was irrelevant but I did mention it, and here it IS relevant and I forgot to add it. I've just added it to the rules, but yes: you can assume the list of words is always in alphabetical order.

Comment: Thanks, that makes a subtle difference to my Retina answer, as I had two versions for the same byte count but the alphabetical ordering allowed me to save a byte on one version.

Comment: @Neil Now I'm curious about your alternative Retina answer. :)

Comment: It wasn't clear whether it was better to take the grid first or the list of words first. With the grid first I match <gridword>...<initial>...<listword>, and it doesn't matter which word the initial matches (although in practice the regex engine will pick the previous word) but with the list of words first I have to ensure I only match one <initial>, which costs a byte, although it would be faster on really large grids.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>12 11</s>  8 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

-3 thanks to @KevinCruijssen (take the wordsearch as a mulitline list of characters).

```
=Ḣ¥ƝŻḋẇ€
```

A dyadic Link that accepts the list of words on the left and the wordsearch (a multiline list of characters) on the right and yields a non-negative integer.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FU45DsIwEOz3TxTrxHGOTTbBi5Dd0yA@QEtDwRtokBANJUVEOhD8I3zE2MWMRiPNsd3sdvsQFvN4eV2/5880j6f5efwd7mGeHu9bCAqJQKGA0riMRFGxgyw6Ga8hZwMGCUrs8kgCbZVpsCVrEO4jnAWPfaipUn3nB8Y6h0YV2HqbGhkYG0mhTAYDjihlc2SzAktlnPBKHJbQpgWLXFnCVF0VrndoagHtJd3SKOj/)**

#### How?

```
=Ḣ¥ƝŻḋẇ€ - Link: words W (list of lists of characters); wordsearch P (list of characters)
   Ɲ     - for neighbouring words in W:
  ¥      -   last two links as a dyad - f(left, right):
=        -     left equals right (vectorises)
 Ḣ       -     head
    Ż    - prepend a zero
           -> E = a list of 1s and 0s identifying whether the previous
                  word stated with the same letter.
       € - for each Word in W:
      ẇ  -   is Word a sublist of P?
           -> F = a list of 1s and 0s identifying whether the current
                  word is in the wordsearch
     ḋ   - E dot-product F
```

Comment: Can you save bytes by taking the grid as a multi-line string so you don't need the `K`?

Answer (score 5):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>73</s> <s>69</s> 68 bytes

*Edit: -1 byte thanks to pajonk*

```r
function(g,w)sum((c(l<-substr(w,1,1),T)==c(T,l))[sapply(w,grepl,g)])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVDBbpwwFLz3KyxOINFD7t3Ds/0Arw2P2E5ZqKKoWW1XVelmBVlF/fqt7SSHqL3M2Dw8b2aW6@Py9Otwelgu82HdXH9cTvvnn0@n/Fi@FOvld57v8/nL5/XyuD4v@Ut5U94UpS82m33uy7kovq3fz@f5T5gcl8N5Lo/FffFBMs@2RvG@m24JtpJpXkE7OY5giRFo3yqBwt/WbDTGNYQSqL5jzjSChon7ERrWNtBJB6ScAeapV9XYj1BvPcPJczQewcOUlfs842BMVgbyEcOSRCbdaAwo0iRoB5RUB6whvogrEsVx9BQo2gkUNiYcXaAJ@qwoPn1MCFwwF/Jo2CUXwMOf4HREm852F3H379PhK1qvRLDNLBFUlXHAGQirjAJPwDpJUlM3SMGk1eiIpNSMEPsJa6MG1jqlGgK0wMBYba2yaJkmqSRKKyRr0AzO4J1v3ioSegAb00oFNXUpf6Ve85NVE3U@fbOhE2pjEYgxy7tI9u45HAelVY9BKJ7JShc6F81/KhqDE6zqhknB4a0lEUsZIwqeIKqI6AOrBHVUuv4F)

Function with arguments `g`=grid, as a single string with each line in the grid separated by spaces (newlines would also be fine), and `w`=words, as a vector of individual words.

Comment: Simple [-1](https://tio.run/##bVDBbpwwFLz3KyxOINFD7t3Ds/0Arw2P2E5ZqKKoWW1XVelmBVlF/fqt7SSHqL3M2Dw8b2aW6@Py9Otwelgu82HdXH9cTvvnn0@n/Fi@FOvld57v8/nL5/XyuD4v@Ut5U94UpS82m33uy7kovq3fz@f5T5gcl8N5Lo/FffFBMs@2RvG@m24JtpJpXkE7OY5giRFo3yqBwt/WbDTGNYQSqL5jzjSChon7ERrWNtBJB6ScAeapV9XYj1BvPcPJczQewcOUlfs842BMVgbyEcOSRCbdaAwo0iRoB5RUB6whvogrEsVx9BQo2gkUNiYcXaAJ@qwoPn1MCFwwF/Jo2CUXwMOf4HREm852F3H379PhK1qvRLDNLBFUlXHAGQirjAJPwDpJUlM3SMGk1eiIpNSMEPsJa6MG1jqlGgK0wMBYba2yaJkmqSRKKyRr0AzO4J1v3ioSegAb00oFNXUpf6Ve85NVE3U@fbOhE2pjEYgxy7tI9u45HAelVY9BKJ7JShc6F81/KhqDE6zqhknB4a0lEUsZIwqeIKqI6AOrBHVUuv4F)

Comment: @pajonk - Ah, yes, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 58 bytes

```python
lambda n,k:sum(a[0]==b[0]*(b in n)for a,b in zip(k,k[1:]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVJRb9owEH6/X5G3kApNm/YyVeLhYjuJieGo7S5NKEIwYIugAZGgafvzzIbSdopy0d35@7774jv86X7tm6/fDsfzZvB83i1elqtF0PS39@3ppbeYfp4NBksX73rLoG6CJtrsj8Gif0n@1ofetr@dfrmfRdG5W7fdj0W7boNBEIbhUMl4Mq4eCIcc8jjBUWVigZqAMLcjyQSzDymUSpmMBEdKH8GojFFRxbbEDEYZjrlBkkYhWJrIpJyUmA4tiMrGQlmBFiuAGJVywYJnB9@AmEpgruLIgFMKKSrwbC5Y8NLgNT2pe0sDFU4AAGMGxs2X45NPAE0OqN1XP4EvQfFdaCuZ19NEmCTK@GNMSyXREsKYE89pXHAGXOfCEHGeAwkxqUSqZAEjI2VGKDQCKp1rLbXQkBOXXHDN3IBCFUaJR5t5YywvUHPgElMaOw@J9B5Iy4rG1uXaeaIRGCFyeEXdRoRC5nIiHBQK0ty4f8Myb7J0KiJJM@AsxqtpVwMWg88vzUvfXeGn9rCru1743PgnjADq5nDq/AVP23U3/9gPo8Bvhi/71Xhbhhns6rabvwOnP4/1qh/83h9Xc3f6nSOMZheK//ue7Aqewf7U3Vg2vbsbb3tVfks94oPmDOBwrJuu94qOzv8A)

Takes the grid (`n`) as a string that includes newlines, and the list of words (`k`) as a... list of words.

Simple. Find the number of consecutive pairs in `k` that have the same starting letter and where the second word in the pair is in the grid. The grid is a newline string, so if a word is present horizontally, then somewhere in the grid, there is a run of letters equal to that word that is not cut off by any newline.

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 33 bytes

```
ＷＳ⊞υι≔⁰θＷＳ«≧⁺∧№⪫υ¶ι⁼§ι⁰ψθ≔§ι⁰ψ»Ｉθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY3LasMwEEXXma8wWUngQvZZjWzFj8iRE6kUm25MEmyDUR6W@6D0212JdNcu5sLMXM45ds39eGmGeX7v@uEckMxcJ6vsvTctoTQop7EjUxj0dA04jn1ryCoMbm77v/8Fi6K5PpqHvu0sKYdpDAM0JxJdJmNJfumNJy5fzZJ6cBjw29QMI0GbmdP5g/RhsHLXT0ofpsWv@M9/Dd9QOrMlUTNacqN0Pc@5yFi5q/cS8xi2bINFrRjHgwSJW11kEY/0PoFKCJVKHqNMnkGJNJIvNdMVplCkuIsVykwJBC3LbFOVFSa5Bl5rxoXmqLEGYCiECw2eDv4BTFYQuYuDQSwTSFCAp7nQ4NXgnR7qplJQYwnz09vwAw) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes both grid and list as a newline-terminated list of newline-separated strings. Explanation:

```
ＷＳ⊞υι
```

Read in the grid.

```
≔⁰θ
```

Start with no matching words.

```
ＷＳ«
```

Loop through the list.

```
≧⁺∧№⪫υ¶ι⁼§ι⁰ψθ
```

If the current word is a left-to-right word and its first letter is the same as that of the previous word then increment the count.

```
≔§ι⁰ψ
```

Save the first letter of this word for the next iteration of the loop.

```
»Ｉθ
```

Output the final count.

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup>36</sup> 31 bytes

```
1#.(0,2=&{.&>/\[)*1#.,@E.&>/@,:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVBNb9QwEL2/X2GBtNtF2bAtnEIX7fgjiTfeTGq7pEmROKBWiAsHekPw1xe720pFHMbj@Xhv5s3346tyeS@2lViKQmxElWxdCuVdfTx/XZ5tiovt4le5@Pj28@3qTcoUO5OjXVEdV@hlKf5tKarnnuKpDQ93Px@2pbj7@u3HbituK3F2dp/d5a4QxWIplh/KLxerP@Ly0SfQ6bf7XQHvREbnvTbYOyuHfr5i2mt0sqbDHKQhz2Dq4sEqo@JVg8m50LLRxM01gmsVj7OME7U4tNTrQGyDI0QebD0NEzX7CDNHaVw0FGnGWpJzkBSR2ZELkDxBpUwig@YGDTlktvRE5NHIMzNpsilgpgFrrACcv1BAUiGkfTu6wZokKHQgn7y/QU79Bxg/GR@tyvt4ZqprFzJMeessRSb0mnXH/agVtO9MYNa6AxszzKZxdsQhWNsyGU8g5zvvrTceHWurjfYqCTBuDM5cxzYLV91IXkNbarhPGmubNbK3M/cxxT5p5gOCMR2eUM8rYrSdHUyCYmSvQ7qdak@a3r@8wZSGmrppoZWkfAaVc1ASOX4snuoJevwL)

*-5 stealing dominic's idea of taking the matrix lines as a single space-delimited string*

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 13 bytes

```
2lƛvh≈⁰ẋntc;∑
```

[Try it Online](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCIybMabdmjiiYjigbDhuotudGM74oiRIiwiIiwiW1wiQkFMTFwiLCBcIkJBVFwiLCBcIkJFQVJcIiwgXCJCRUxUXCIsIFwiQk9ZXCIsIFwiQ0FUXCIsIFwiQ09XXCIsIFwiRE9HXCIsIFwiR0FMXCIsIFwiSEFORFwiLCBcIkhBVFwiLCBcIk1JQ0VcIiwgXCJTSE9FXCIsIFwiVE9QXCIsIFwiVE9ZU1wiLCBcIlpBUFwiXVxuSkxJQlBOWlFPQUpEICBLQkZBTVpTQkVBUk8gIE9BS1RNSUNFQ1RRRyAgWUxMU0hPRURBT0dVICBTTEhDT1daQlRZQUggIE1IQU5EU0FPSVNMQSAgVE9QSUZZUFlBR0pUICBFWlRCRUxURUFUQVoiXQ==) or [run all the test cases](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCJAZjphOmJ84oaQYSIsIjrhuKJa4bmqxpt2aOKJiOKGkGLhuotudGM74oiRIiwiO1xuxpvDtyRAZjs7IiwiW1tbXCJCQUxMXCIsIFwiQkFUXCIsIFwiQkVBUlwiLCBcIkJFTFRcIiwgXCJCT1lcIiwgXCJDQVRcIiwgXCJDT1dcIiwgXCJET0dcIiwgXCJHQUxcIiwgXCJIQU5EXCIsIFwiSEFUXCIsIFwiTUlDRVwiLCBcIlNIT0VcIiwgXCJUT1BcIiwgXCJUT1lTXCIsIFwiWkFQXCJdLFwiSkxJQlBOWlFPQUpEXFxuS0JGQU1aU0JFQVJPXFxuT0FLVE1JQ0VDVFFHXFxuWUxMU0hPRURBT0dVXFxuU0xIQ09XWkJUWUFIXFxuTUhBTkRTQU9JU0xBXFxuVE9QSUZZUFlBR0pUXFxuRVpUQkVMVEVBVEFaXCJdLFtbXCJBQlwiLFwiQVNLXCIsXCJBUkJcIixcIkFSWFwiLFwiQVhcIl0sXCJBQkNcXG5TUk9cXG5LQVhcIl0sW1tcIkJBQ0tXQVJEXCIsXCJESUFHT05BTFwiLFwiRklORFwiLFwiSE9SSVpPTlRBTFwiLFwiUkFORE9NXCIsXCJTRUVLXCIsXCJTTEVVVEhcIixcIlZFUlRJQ0FMXCIsXCJXSUtJUEVESUFcIixcIldPUkRTRUFSQ0hcIl0sXCJXVkVSVElDQUxMXFxuUk9PQUZGTFNBQlxcbkFDUklMSUFUT0FcXG5ORE9ES09OV0RDXFxuRFJLRVNPT0RES1xcbk9FRVBaRUdMSVdcXG5NU0lJSE9BRVJBXFxuQUxSS1JSSVJFUlxcbktPRElERURSQ0RcXG5IRUxXU0xFVVRIXCJdLFtbXCJBQkNcIixcIkFZQ1wiLFwiQ0JcIixcIkNCQVwiLFwiQ0RcIixcIkVGXCIsXCJFRkdIXCJdLFwiQVlDRFxcbkVGR0hcXG5EQ0JBXCJdXSJd).

### How?

```
2lƛvh≈⁰ẋntc;∑
2l            # Get a list of overlapping pairs in the (implicit) first input
  ƛ           # Map over them:
   vh         # Get the first character of both
     ≈        # Are they equal?
      ⁰       # Push the second input
       ẋ      # Repeat (so if the first characters are not equal, empty string, else second input)
        n     # Push the pair again
         t    # Get the second item in the pair
          c   # Does the other string contain this string?
           ;  # Close map lambda
            ∑ # Summate
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 25 bytes

```
&`((.).+).*;.*\b\2.+,\1\b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FY29jsIwEIT7eRDEnywdLdU6cZyEDRvwImQrBSBdcc0ViGfjAXixYBfzFTPSN8/f19//ff68P2/skbGdF7fl0qzMZmXWe7OeHtPObLbTz/SY5547Ox7TSaivcbANDSlYR2eB0EGHrnKVnjwic2jF1ST@gsBtJddkNVKLoaVjHUi6wASVsWviGMn3CpfUOlZHSgmwxJyhKHaUAVYiqtxkGWrx8MQotgxFuUb5LNKcGJBo/AI) Takes input as two semicolon-separated comma-delimited lists but link includes header that converts from newline-separated for convenience. Explanation:

```
&`
```

Count the number of overlapping matches (except only match once at any given starting position).

```
((.).+).*;
```

Match a word in the grid.

```
.*\b\2.+
```

Check that its first letter appears in another word in the list.

```
,\1\b
```

Check that the word appears in the list.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 12 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ü2ε€нË×yθå}O
```

Since there hasn't been a 05AB1E answer yet, I'm gonna post my prepared solution.

First input is a list of words; second the grid as a multi-line string.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##Jc6tDsIwEAdw36cg1Sje4LZu3Ue362gJaQkCEgQKgUJgsDwAT4DDkiBAzS88Ay8ydqv65XIf/zscN9v9ru/b96x7/i6P76e9trdT92rvZ@z7FY9AKT6dDNqRBOZBFWp0RBy6MS4JgZKQMG5mUIvgOFPlcUKaDEct6oAzpAfN14xzXqg80rVvEArByiiFyhtKR4ZQWroS20YypxRdEoBywYzKhhd8ZB1krKJgA5gbBWxIyVOnHcjCssRb@j8BC35I@gM) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##NVCxbtswEN3zFQFndelYoAhOJCXRpHUKSVeWLANJ0aIwULBF7RTI0KVrP6Bf0K1rgw7NEu9BvqE/4t7R7nLvdHp899592F6/3rw9fBYmfbzZPXu/2e5enIuL26ttcXaavfu0eUOz4uXi4e7iTODNjqaZ9HR/2P95/vjr79efT/f7b8v999vH3/sfX/BQPNwVh9VqJUpwThTnhDGDBn9Ed/zGgUEe/0rsGRTWDDXklw206oiZMzdSM4YGM0bsjjAExhE6sS7EzJmya8dLhJmaki0rmI@Bl@OUEGxkFRkv6ykNzrGUAqwXUwquIRNjGQdopjTn3QHQBAdTok2mGroB6lmckh4jh9AQYaSNFBVKUQgIlqvPvV9yXbIhKCWp83qbB/k00vbgKZxQBmpsOa@oDMcVDXozYhvzzJMNnFMTtGb54PQiNtS80j4amTm9sabTJMQ9ehUorGx4df@f5abkEaGqXIBySiC9cQYiUjbSVxbbXpFL5a0OiEpZupXW3ahrZ3q6RjCmQdCe@OC89d547SkQKqO08pIu3WjXn9ydbiL5BANXWebCBiVH1FUudTZJFHrOX2SASev1Pw).

**Explanation:**

```python
ü2         # Create overlapping pairs of the first (implicit) input-list of words
  ε        # Map over each overlapping pair:
   €       #  Map over both words:
    н      #   Only leave their first character
     Ë     #  Check if both first characters are the same
      ×    #  Repeat the second (implicit) input-grid by that check
           #  (so the grid itself if truthy, or an empty string if falsey)
       y   #  Push the pair of words again
        θ  #  Pop and leave the last word
         å #  Check if its in the grid (or empty string)
  }O       # After the map: sum to get the amount of truthy values
           # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```